# Kafka Server Start Command is Not Working

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

I am New to Apache Kafka, I am trying to run **.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties** command from a windows machine to start Kafka server but I am not Getting any kind of response to the Command-Prompt screen, neither any Error message nor any success message, it just threw me to a new command line. Although I am able to run Zookeeper Server successfully. I have updated server.properties and zookeeper.properties file properly. Also, I have set Java Path correctly.

[image: Here I am trying to start the Kafka-Server but it just sends me to the next command line without any message]

[image: Here You can see that zookeeper-server is running properly without any issue.]

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: There is a `KAFKA_DEBUG` variable that you could play with, or find/edit the `log4j.properties` to get any more information... Otherwise, know that Kafka isn't really tested on Windows and there are many open issues for it

Comment: It's not exactly an answer to what you want, but I would recommend starting with Confluent platform to use Kafka! you will have a managed local cluster that can be ran by `confluent local services kafka start`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue has resolved for me after I added a line in User Variable Path in Environment Variable.

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\System32\;SystemRoot%
```

Comment: How did this line change your luck with Kafka?

Comment: @raikumardipak I guess I have not added Kafka to path variables.